# AssertEqual failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, lodash, assertion

I wrote a program to compare arrays and to implement without method just like in Lodash. Everything worked fine except the test I wrote to test my result using assertEqual function, I do not know why the test is failing.

```js
const assertEqual = function (actual, expected) {
  if (actual === expected) {
    console.log(`✅✅✅ Assertion Passed: ${actual} === ${expected}`);
  } else {
    console.log(` Assertion Failed: ${actual} !== ${expected}`);
  }

  return;
};

const eqArrays = function (arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

assertEqual(eqArrays([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]), true);

const without = function (source, itemsToRemove) {
  let newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    if (!itemsToRemove.includes(source[i])) {
      newArray.push(source[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}


console.log(without([1, 2, 3], [1]));
console.log(without(['1', '2', '3'], [1, 2, '3']));

assertEqual(without([1, 2, 3], [1]), [2, 3]);
```

Comment: I don't see any lodash code there.

Comment: Your `assertEqual` call at the end _doesn't_ use `eqArrays` - non-primitive values are compared by _reference_, `[2, 3] === [2, 3]` is `false`. I would change that code to have `assertEqual` _use_ `eqArrays` if passed arrays, otherwise you get the unhelpful `Assertion Failed: false !== true`.

Comment: I think this is just a typo. `assertEqual(without([1, 2, 3], [1]), [2, 3]);` should be `assertEqual(eqArrays(without([1, 2, 3], [1]), [2, 3]), true);` (just like your first test that passes).

Comment: Just as a mention: you added code, which works, and is completely irrelevant to the question (the entire `eqArrays` thing, never used later), but it added a scroll bar i missed, and i read "the test", saw one test, which worked. You almost shot yourself in the foot there for no reason?

Comment: Oh! My bad. It works now with `assertEqual(eqArrays(without([1, 2, 3], [1]), [2, 3]), true);`

Answer (score -1):

I changed

```
assertEqual(without([1, 2, 3], [1]), [2, 3]);
```

to

```
assertEqual(eqArrays(without([1, 2, 3], [1]), [2, 3]), true);
```

I made a mistake of omitting the functions eqArrays.

Comment: Please don't just dump updated code in - at the very least explain what you've changed, ideally along with _why_. In this case, given the nature of the mistake, I'd probably recommend just deleting the question.